# Почему не отображается подсказка?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="CPU Loading" Binding="{Binding CPULoading, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="5*">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Почему при ошибке валидации не отображается подсказка с текстом ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стиль для ошибок нужно применять не к `DataGridCell`, а к текстбоксу, который показывает текст. Для этого нужно заменить установку `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle` на вот что:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```